# How to have variable rows (dynamic data) in a column of html table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

If I have a table like this:

[image: my table]

The first row with the Name Bob has 3 sub rows under the patient column. I can't figure out how to set something like this up. In my searching I can across column/row span but the problem is that I is unknown how many Patients/Meetings there will be for any particular Name. The data is dynamic. Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: You could always create a new table within a "super cell" with the data for Patient and Meetings for Patient.